# URL Rewriting using htaccess giving error 404

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi I am new to URL Rewriting. Using htaccess I want to rewrite:

URL: https://example.com/services/state.php?state=CO&city=Arvada

to

https://example.com/services/CO/Arvada/

I tried following but it is giving 404 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([A-Za-z]+)&city=([A-Za-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^services/state\.php$ /services/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

state.php file is located in root/services directory while htaccess file is located in root directory.

Comment: _"but it is giving 404 error"_ - for which URL? The one you originally requested (then that would mean your condition and/or pattern did not match, although they appear to do so) - or for the rewritten one? Do you get a 301 response with a location header first, or just the 404 immediately?

Comment: 404 error is for rewriten URL and I get it immediately

Comment: That makes no sense. If you did not get a 301 response first, then you would not have been redirected _to_ the second URL in the first place.

Comment: And if you are getting a 404 for the desired target URL, then that means your system was not able to properly handle that target URL in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the rule for the URL: `https://example.com/services/CO/Arvada/` that's why you get 404 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rule for services/STATE/CITY/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /services/state.php?state=$1&city=$2 [END]

# Redirect state.php?state=STATE&city=CITY to services/STATE/CITY
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([A-Za-z]+)&city=([A-Za-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^services/state\.php$ services/%1/%2 [QSD, R=301,END]
```

Here is better using `END` instead of `L` because with `END` Apache will not process any other rules, if you use `L` using these rules it will fall in a redirect loop

In the rule:

`RewriteRule ^services/state\.php$ services/%1/%2 [QSD, R=301,END]` the `QSD` means to not append query string

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working. However I am getting %3f at the end of URL and thats why output is not what is expected. I tried adding [QSD,END] at the end of the 1st rule to no avail.

Comment: Sorry you right, I modified the answer, just add `QSD` to the last rule and remove the `?` in that rule

Comment: Can you please guide me on appending page number to rewritten URL. I have updated 1st rule but its not working as expected: RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/page/(\d+)/?$ /services/state.php?state=$1&city=$2&page=$3 [END]

Comment: That must work. Do you test the rules by entering `http://.... state.php?state=CO&city=Arvada&page=45`? Or just `http://....services/CO/Arvada/page/45`? You have to change both rules to make it work with `page`

Comment: @ttony thanks for correcting me. Trying to figure out another scenario with no luck. 3rd parameter of my URL can be species or page number or sort-by Or URL may contain one/two of these or all of these. How to cater for it? `RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /services/state.php?state=$1&city=$2&pet=$3 [END]` gives expected output but `RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /services/state.php?state=$1&city=$2&sortby=$3 [END]` written under previous rule gives wrong output.

Comment: Both RewriteRules: `^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$` and `^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$` are equals, the server will only process the first one in the htaccess file, each RewriteRule must be different, see these examples: `services/CO/Arvada/Dog` and `services/CO/Arvada/ASC` are different URLs but inside Apache server those URLs are processed by the same rule because these are not unique

Comment: You can use this rule for pets for example: `^services/pet/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /state.php?state=$1&city=$2&pet=$3` now for page and sortby there are many ways to do it, but I suggest that sortby be the last in the URL

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. In order to deal with same url pattern issue, I am trying to rewrite `https://example.org/services/state.php?state=TX&city=Austin&{other 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 optional parameters}` To `https://example.org/services/tx/austin?{query string(containing all optional parameters after City)}` . So anything after City should be appended to url as query string. Please note the **/?** at the end of City of desired URL. Also I want the rewritten URL in lower case. Please guide